# Using FilesystemIterator in a foreach loop to generate image library

Tags: php

I have this code inside a `php` file:

```
<?php
   function convertToReadableSize($size){
   $base = log($size) / log(1024);
   $suffix = array("", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB");
   $f_base = floor($base);
   return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), 1) . $suffix[$f_base];
}
   $file_path = 'online_assets/images/';
    ?>
```

With a repeating loop displaying every entry:

```
<?php
   $fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('online_assets/images/');

      foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $fileInfo){
      $entries[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <a href="<?php echo $file_path;?>Room.jpg" target="new">
                    <img src="/slir/w320-h180-c320x180/<?php echo $file_path;?>Room.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h4 class="red"><?php $filename;?></h4>
                    <p>Filesize: <?php echo convertToReadableSize(filesize($cannery_file_path . 'Room.jpg'));?><br>Format: jpg<br>Quality: <?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_path . 'Room.jpg'); echo ($width) .  "&nbsp;x&nbsp;" . ($height); ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $file_path;?>Room.jpg" target="new">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download Here</button></a>                 
                </div>
            </div>
<?php } ?>
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is a loop that will return a value essentially `foreach` image inside the `/images/` folder - so all the client has to do is upload images to that folder and they appear, with a thumbnail, file information and a link to download.

I have the rest working, but the loop is giving me some troubles. What am I missing for this?

I picked the code for the FileSystemIterator from the php online manual.

Comment: You have a loop to store all files in `$entries`, but you do not use this array later in the code...

Comment: The original code contained a `var_dump($entries);
//OUTPUT
object(FilesystemIterator)[0]` and I removed it because it was showing all the files in a dump, basically.